# How can one retrieve the "rich display" HTML from an object?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

How can one retrieve the HTML string that the IPython notebook is generating to display that object (within Python, I am not after inspecting the HTML source from my browser) ?

Answer (score 2):

call  `_repr_html_` directly:

```
from IPython.display import display
class Foo(object):

    def _repr_html_(self):
        return "<b>HTML</b>"

display(Foo())  #display HTML in bold
Foo()._repr_html_()  # return "<b>HTML</b>"
```

this works only if the object implement the `_repr_*_` itself. If formatters are registered on IPython for an object you can roughly access it like that : `get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['text/html'].for_type(your_object)` but you have only a small chance that you need to use this method.